# How to control bitrates in safari webrtc?

Tags: ios, safari, webrtc

I've tried both inserting b=AS and b=TIAS in SDP.

But it does not work in safari.

Is there any way to control it?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I've misunderstood. b=AS works in safari.